# Hide where I'm sshing to?

Tags: ssh, freebsd

I'm connected to a public FreeBSD system, and I want to be able to connect to other servers without disclosing (via `w` and alike) where I'm connecting to, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Depends on the privileges you have.

Comment: @schaiba I'm just a user, though I can compile software under my home directory if required. Are there specific packages I can use to achieve this?

Comment: your are aware that `netstat -an` will include IP of established connection  with destination port=22 ?

Answer (score 2):

The kernel will keep track of your connection, and there's not much you can do about it. I'm not even sure *root* privileges will help you here *(at least not without some kernel module magic)*.

If you want to hide *where* you're going, the best way is probably to pretend you're going *somewhere else* instead. In other words : use a proxy or anything which could **safely** relay the SSH connection.

<sup>**Big** emphasis on **safely** here. Make sure to maintain end-to-end encryption, and don't let a third-party open the SSH channel for you.</sup>

You could for example use [`torsocks`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/torsocks), which will allow you to relay a TCP stream through ToR. This way, instead of `lsof` revealing...

```
$ ssh remotehost

$ lsof SSH_PID              # in another terminal
ssh   SSH_PID   you   TCP   localhost:xx->remotehost:ssh (ESTABLISHED)
```

You would get...

```
$ torsocks ssh remotehost

$ lsof SSH_PID              # in another terminal
ssh   SSH_PID   you   TCP   localhost:yy->localhost:9050 (ESTABLISHED)
```

The difference here is that `ssh` will connect to your local ToR SOCKS server, and not directly to the remote host. What's nice with ToR here is that even the local ToR process won't reveal your destination :

```
$ lsof TOR_PID
tor   TOR_PID   tor   TCP   localhost:zz->tornode:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

([the ToR server connects to a ToR node first](https://www.torproject.org/about/overview))

The other advantage here is that not only do you hide the destination from the source, but you'll also hide the source from the destination. The remote host you're connecting to will see a connection coming from the ToR network. Now of course, depending on who the other system administrator is, this little trick might not work for very long.

With some tweaking, it might be possible to install something similar with user space privileges. You could probably compile something in your home directory and get going. If not, then you'll probably have to choose something else for relaying. A possibility would be to "sacrifice" a remote machine to act as a relay for the others : you would always `ssh` on that one first before connecting to the others.

Answer (score 0):

Since `w` is printing out the process command-line of the process controlled by your terminal, it will just show what you typed in the command line. So you just need to modify the hostname.

Per Gilles' comment, you can set up `.ssh/config` as follows:

```
Host bogusname
HostName real-address.org
Port 2222
# <other options>
```

On the command line, you can connect via

```
ssh bogusname
```

Make the config file read-only and you've got it semi-secret.

However, this won't prevent someone from determining the answer using `netstat -nap` or something similar. But it might at least look innocuous enough so that people who use `w` won't become suspicious.

Comment: No need for something so complex — define aliases in `.ssh/config` and type `ssh myalias42` instead of `ssh compromisingaddress.com`. But that's moot since `netstat` will reveal the target.

Comment: @Gilles didn't know that was possiib.e updating answer.